# Export Plotly scatter as kml - python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, kml

Is it possible to export a Plotly scatter figure as a kml file? I've got an example below using `matplotlib` but is it possible to execute the same output using Plotly?

The Plotly figure is a scatter plot. Can it be converted to a kml output? I'm returning an error when trying to export as a kml.

```
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd
import simplekml
import matplotlib.pyplot as ppl
from pylab import rcParams

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))

gdf['LON'] = gdf['geometry'].x
gdf['LAT'] = gdf['geometry'].y

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(data_frame = gdf, 
                               lat = 'LAT', 
                               lon = 'LON',
                               zoom = 1,
                               mapbox_style = 'carto-positron', 
                               )

fig.show()

fig.write_image('test.kml')
```

Output:

```
ValueError: Invalid format 'kml'.
Supported formats: ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'webp', 'svg', 'pdf', 'eps', 'json']
```

Comment: Do you want a groundoverlay image created from plotly or simply the lat/lon coordinates and city names exported in vector layer as Placemarks in KML?

Comment: I'm using this dataset as an example. The data I'm working with is different. I'm also creating different outputs with Plotly including heat maps. I'm trying to export these figures as a kml file

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate KML from the "naturalearth_cities" dataset as a set of placemarks with a point geometry then you can directly create KML from the *GeoDataFrame* using the [*to_file()*](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_file.html) function. You can skip displaying the data in plotly.

Note KML is disabled in Fiona (which is used by geopandas) by default, so it must be enabled before using it.

Python code to write GeoDataFrame to KML output:

```python
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))

# enable KML driver which is disable by default
gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = "rw"

# With newer versions of Fiona, you might need to use libkml
gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['LIBKML'] = "rw"

gdf.to_file('test.kml', driver='KML')
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document id="root_doc">
    ...
    <Placemark id="test.200">
        <name>Paris</name>
        <ExtendedData>
          <SchemaData schemaUrl="#test.schema">
            <SimpleData name="LON">2.33138946713035</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="LAT">48.8686387898146</SimpleData>
          </SchemaData>
        </ExtendedData>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>
            2.33138946713035,48.8686387898146,0
          </coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
...
```

If you want to add a custom style to the KML output, you can instead iterate over the *GeoDataFrame* and create the KML with simplekml.

Comment: Thanks. So do add point data to the kml output, do you use the gpd file?

Comment: gpd is alias for geopandas package

Comment: @jonboy does the above generate KML output that you can use?

Comment: The "naturalearth_cities" data is just an example. I have custom point data and custom Plotly figures. I'm hoping to replicate the same matplotlib process (outlined in the question) but swap for Plotly